# Access value of a variable from one if statement into another if statement

Tags: python

Hi All I have a function that have if conditions. I am trying to access the same value of noise within the first if statement in the second if statement but I get different values. I am not really sure whats causing that. Below is my sample code for demonstration:

```
x = input(" ")

def sample():

   if scale.get() == 0:
      noise = np.random.normal(0, 5, 20)
      img  = images + noise
      print(noise)

   if len(x) != 0:
      if scale.get() == 0:
          img = images + noise
          print(noise)

#the noise values in both if statements are different. 
#I am not sure why they are different
```

Comment: they're not different, they can't possibly be different (unless `+` does an in place operation but that's highly unlikely)

Comment: Are you sure you didn't do `noise = np.random.normal` again in the second `if`?

Comment: They are inside the same namespace. If this is exactely what you are executing, either noise is not being defined when scale.get!=0 and you are getting an error when executing "img = images + noise" because noise is not defined or they must be the same variable.

Comment: you need to provide a [mre], as it currently stands, the behavior you're describing is unlikely to happen with the given code

Comment: @MarcoMontevechiFilho, there is no scale.get()!=0 case in my code. I just need the same noise value in the second if statement

Comment: @daniel then cant you get rid of the first if since it will always be executed?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldnt this be a simple fix?

```
x = input(" ")

def sample():
   noise = np.random.normal(0, 5, 20)

   if scale.get() == 0:
      img  = images + noise
      print(noise)

   if len(x) != 0:
      if scale.get() == 0:
          img = images + noise
          print(noise)

#the noise values in both if statements are different. 
#I am not sure why they are different
```

Comment: Nope, I am still getting different values. I am not sure if its because of the nested if statement in the second if statement

Comment: Are you trying to say that the random value `noise` is different for every invocation? Please note that every invocation of the random number generator will change the seed number. If you want to fix the value for multiple invocations of the function, you should fix the seed number. Please check out https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.seed.html?highlight=seed#numpy.random.seed where you can pick a seed number for the `np.random` methods.